# How to design a adjustable pulse generator?

Tags: signal-generator

I want to design a pulse generator module to output pulse signals with specified characteristics according to the command of the host computer or MCU. The requirements are as follows:

1. The rise time (10%-90%) of the output pulse signal is between 300ps-400ps, no need to control and adjust
2. The pulse width of the output signal is about 1ns, no need to adjust and control
3. The amplitude of the output pulse signal is between 0-10V, continuously adjustable
4. The frequency of the output signal signal is adjustable, and the frequency needs to be higher than 20kHz

In other words, the host computer or MCU will send two control commands: frequency and amplitude.

I noticed that there is an avalanche pulse generator that can send out a pulse signal of about 10V and a rise time of about 350ps, but the frequency and amplitude of this module are not adjustable, only the rise time meets the demand:

Fast Edge Pulse Generator 350 Picosecond Rising Edge:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004649319197.html

Can anyone provide some advice on how to design this pulse generator?  If possible, please attach a simple schematic or system diagram?

2023-5-26 edit:
I found a circuit that can trigger the output pulse:
[image: Triggered 250 Picosecond Rise Time Pulse Generator]

The source of the circuit is : https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an61fa.pdf
on page 21

Comment: Avalanche pulse generator can be triggered with a base drive network. This solves frequency. Amplitude can be adjusted by selectable attenuator (which can be constructed with PIN diodes). An arbitrary number of steps can be used, approximating a continuous adjustable range. Would this suffice?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams. I'm OK with the triggered network. I am a little confused about the "selectable attenuator". Can you draw some simple schematic about the "selectable attenuator" ? Could you make the attenuator newtork be controlled by digital(or MCU)?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have searched the PIN diode attenuator. It can be controlled by MCU(DAC voltage). I will draw some schematic and test. Thank you

Comment: Please include the source of your figure.

Comment: I have added the source of the circuit.

Comment: The source looks like it would be extremely sensitive to parasitics and exact board layout, even dielectric choice. Just a copper trace can have 1pF to 10pF depending on how it is laid out.  What is more important is the "See Text" and choice of [2N2369](https://www.taitroncomponents.com/catalog/Datasheet/2N2369.pdf) which is fast (15ns), but likely not one of the fastest transistors available today.  This hasn't gotten an answer because it would require much effort to solve, and likely would not work right if made on a JLCPCB board vs. OshPark.

Comment: I found a AVALANCHE TRANSISTOR: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Bipolar-Transistors-BJT_Diodes-Incorporated-FMMT413TD_C193670.html     I'll try this transistor